# Array value not gettting removed

Tags: angular

I have two components. 1) product component that adds products to a cart. 2) A cart component that can view and remove the products that were added. My problem is that the cart component doesn't really remove the products. When I click remove, it hides the product from the view but if I navigate back to the product page and return the to cart page then I can see the product that was hidden.

Here is my code

*Service*

```
  private eventSource = new ReplaySubject();
  public event$ = this.eventSource.asObservable();

  getAllProducts() {
    return this.http.get<IProductsAvailable[]>("https://fakestoreapi.com/products")
  }

  public setEvent(value) {
    this.eventSource.next(value);
  }
```

*Product component*

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loading = true;
    this.productsService.getAllProducts().subscribe({
      next: (res) => {
        this.loading = false;
        this.productsAvailable = res;
        this.dataSource.data = res;
      },
      error: (error) => {
        this.loading = false;
        alert(error);
      }
    })
  }

  addToCart(product): void {
    this.productsService.setEvent(product);
  }

  goToCart(): void {
    this.router.navigate(['cart']);
  }
```

*Cart component*

```
  cartProducts: Array<any> = [];

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.productsService.event$.subscribe(product => {
      this.cartProducts.push(product);
      this.sum();
    });
  }

  deleteProduct(id) {
    let index = this.cartProducts.findIndex(item => item.id === id);
    this.cartProducts.splice(index, 1);
    this.sum();
  }
```

Stackblitz example

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zdai44?file=src/app/product-list-component/product-list.component.ts

Comment: as per me this is happening because you are using replaySubject instead of BehaviorSubject. and you need to call next on that behavior subject again after removing the item.

Comment: @AakashGarg here is my stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zdai44?file=src/app/product-list-component/product-list.component.ts

Comment: I guess you need to save deleted records IDs in an array and filter your products accordingly.

Comment: @ZainKhan Yes, but how can I pass those deleted ID's to the replay subject

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In product service, i updated replaysubject to behaviorsubject.

```
private eventSource = new BehaviorSubject([]);
```

Then in productslist component i added following variable

```
public products;
```

and in ngOnInit i initialized it with same behavior subject value

```
this.productsService.event$.subscribe((res) => (this.products = res));
```

and modified addToCart method to following

```
addToCart(product): void {
    this.products.push(product);
    this.productsService.setEvent(this.products);
  }
```

In cart.component modified ngOnInit like following :-

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.productsService.event$.subscribe((products) => {
      this.cartProducts = products;
      this.sum();
    });
  }
```

and changed deleteProduct method to following :-

```
deleteProduct(id) {
    let index = this.cartProducts.findIndex((item) => item.id === id);
    this.cartProducts.splice(index, 1);
    this.productsService.setEvent(this.cartProducts);

    this.sum();
  }
```

Stackblitz url :- https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gnye61?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcart%2Fcart.component.ts